# Application crashes after installing iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone

I recently installed iOS 4.2 for my iPod after then my application started to crash.

The scenario is: I launch my application wait until it's up and running then hit the iPod home button then launch my application again, my application starts again for seconds then crashes.

- my application is a job search engine, so in all of its navigation pages it's communicating with internet server.
- I think the problem has to do with applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillEnterForeground, or applicationDidBecomeActive methods. I do not have an code in these methods and I do not know if I need to, to prevent the crash.
- I do not understand what happens after I hit the home button and my application goes to the background:

  - will it still be running in the background (because of the multithreading thing in iOS4.2).
  - Sometimes when I relaunch my application it goes to last page I left in before hitting the home button and sometime it starts from the home page.

I do not understand what's going on, I just want it every time it starts to start in the home page.

I was just about to submit my application to the Apple Store just before I updated to iOS4.2 and the crash starts to happen. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me with this issue that I'm not even able/or know how to debug.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Regards,

Comment: And what do your crash logs say?

Comment: ceejayoz, I'm sorry this might be a stupid question, but I never access my crash log and i do not know how to access it, can you direct me on how to do that?

Comment: KingofBliss, I did not get your question, it's crashing only from the device not the simulator when I relaunch it again.

Comment: K.. it will be of memory issues. Check the memory leaks using instruments

Comment: To check the crash in device, install iphone configuration utility and check the console there

Comment: KingofBliss, regarding the memory issues, I checked the code with the static analyzer and all my variables were properly deallocated. And I also ran my app with Instruments and I did not see any major leaks. Actually to be honest, I do not know how to use Instruments that much, I'd appreciate it if you can point me to any good tutorial that will help me learn how to use it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Info.plist key `ApplicationDoesNotRunOnBackground` to make sure the app is completely terminated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess it seems to be working fine now. But can you please explain to me why is it a bad practice??

Comment: exit(0) is bad one, not this. Thats why i have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, I got that, Thanks. But why exit(0) is a bad practice? is it because I should terminate my application from within my code or my application should be normally running in the background??

Comment: exit(0) may sometimes cause problem

Comment: KindofBliss, I just tried setting ApplicationDoesNotRunOnBackground in info.plist instead of using exit(0), but unfortunately, it did not work!! exit(0) still works fine though. Anyway I just thought you might want to know how did it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode / Organizer will show your device crash logs.

`Xcode -> COMMAND+CONTROL+O -> Device Logs` or you *(making sure the device is connected)* can select the iPod from the list of devices, then choose Device Logs.

You don't need to have any code in the `applicationDidEnterBackground`, `applicationWillEnterForeground`, or `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegates, so that's not making your app crash.

I would definitely check out some of those logs in Organizer. Maybe post some of them here, or [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide, WrightsCS, I was able to see the device logs but it did not actually make any sense to me. I was able to fix my issue using KingofBliss answer above but I'd like to understand what was causing the problem. Here is a snippet of the latest crash log:

Comment: Your reply didnt contain any snippet. Try posting the entire crash log on pastie.org, and we can see what your logs say.

Comment: I actually went to pastie.org and posted my crash log there but I did not know what to do after that. I'm new to pastie.org, so can you tell me what to do. is it that you need the url of my log in pastie.org or what??

Comment: Anyway, here is my crash log URL from pastie.org: http://pastie.org/1392644 Thanks a lot.